# I need to use a string variable as a file name in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open("name.txt", "w") as f1:
    for line in f:
        f1.write(line)
```

I need `open("name.txt", "w")` to be something like `open(variable + ".txt", "w")`; I'm new to python, any help is appreciated!

Thanks to all who helped, this was my final code:

```
with open(f'aWord{name}.txt', "w") as f1:                
   for line in f:
       f1.write(line)
```

Comment: If `variable` is a string, that should work as you have it. for example if you have `variable='name'`, then `open(variable + ".txt", "w")` would be the same as `open("name.txt", "w")`. But that doesn't address the fact that `f` is not defined in your next line: `for line in f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that in multiple ways in python

```
'{}.txt'.format(variable)
'{one}.txt'.format(one=variable)
'%s.txt' % variable
f'{variable}'
```

Then you will have

```
with open('{}.txt'.format(variable), "w") as f1:
    ...
```

Comment: `f"{variable}.txt"` for 3.6+

Comment: you can't do that in python; you will need to use in formats above. `{variable}.txt` literally means "{variable}.txt" as string.

Comment: you might want to freshen up your python 3.6 skills: read about string interpolation https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Wow that `f''` thing is great. Thanks a lot for information. I'll add in the answer too.